# Flutter stop all other players for Audio player

Tags: android, flutter

I'm developing an app that contain multiple audio files for classroom, how can I stop all other players when I want to play a single audio? I've used Listview builder, and named every audio file with different name but I don't know how to reach them again to stop while they are playing now

I I can play and stop single audio, but if I left one of the audio list playing and play a new one, the old one will keep playing

[image]

```
                       ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: 3,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return AudioLectureWidget(
                                  mp3URL:index==0?'https://audio-samples.github.io/samples/mp3/blizzard_unconditional/sample-0.mp3':index==1?'https://audio-samples.github.io/samples/mp3/blizzard_unconditional/sample-5.mp3':'https://audio-samples.github.io/samples/mp3/blizzard_unconditional/sample-4.mp3',
                                  playerId: 'player$index',
                                  title: 'Introduction to Artificial Intelligence',
                                  subTitle: 'Object Oriented Programming',
                                  time: '56:12',
                                );
                              }),
```

AudioLectureWidget:

```
                  onTap: (){
                    playerId.stop();
                    !isPlaying?playerId.play(widget.mp3URL) :playerId.stop();
                    isPlaying = !isPlaying;
                    setState(() { });
                  },
```

Comment: You can use a global instance or a singleton instance of the audioplayer and just call stop before play.

Comment: I'm new to flutter can you explain in details

Comment: Can you edit and add the code of the `AudioLectureWidget` in your question